# Call Intent from handleDecode of zxing

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I am developing an application in which i am reading the QR code using zxing library. I am calling the zxing library for reading QR CODE as:

```
public class QRScanner extends CaptureActivity {
    TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.qrscanner_layout);  
}

@Override 
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_output);
    tv.setText(rawResult.getText());
}
```

Now i want to call new activity from

```
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    //Want to call new activity using intent and pass result in new activity.
}
```

And i tried a code as:

```
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    String result = rawResult.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent(QRScanner.this,Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("Result", result);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But it is not working. As how to test this code on emulator i don't know.

When i try to run this app on device it terminates. What should i do for that. It is my application need that the result of QR code scanning is required in next activity.

Please suggest me what should i do for this.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't said anything about what is "not working" -- specific error?

Comment: The code is not running on emulator as no camera is there on emulator. And when i am running it on device it terminates. So please suggest how to get error log in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare Activity2 in your manifest?  Wrap that getText() in a try-catch ...

```
String result = "";
try {
    result = rawResult.getText();
catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    Log.e("handleDecode()", "Result was null.", npe);
}
```

At least then you're passing "" if the result is null.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it work fine. But after getting result from the same method i want to call new activity through Intent and invoke a new layout with the result. So please guide me for that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason as why the application terminates. As i read a link and then understand that i did not declare the library file in menifest. As i dont know that it should have to declare.

Thank you.